# AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:

Tags: react-native, expo

I am getting below error tried to solve using

```
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
```

instead

```
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
```

but still not working

AppLoading threw an unexpected error when loading:
Error: AppLoading onError prop is required if startAsync is provided
at node_modules/expo-app-loading/build/AppLoading.js:8:12 in startLoadingAppResourcesAsync._catch$argument_0

this is my App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppLoading from 'expo-app-loading';
// import { AppLoading } from "expo";

import navigationTheme from "./app/navigation/navigationTheme";
import AppNavigator from "./app/navigation/AppNavigator";
import OfflineNotice from "./app/components/OfflineNotice";
import AuthNavigator from "./app/navigation/AuthNavigator";
import AuthContext from "./app/auth/context";
import authStorage from "./app/auth/storage";

export default function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState();
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const restoreUser = async () => {
    const user = await authStorage.getUser();
    if(user) setUser(user);
  }

  if(!isReady)
    return (
      <AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
    );

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ user, setUser }}>
      <OfflineNotice />
      <NavigationContainer theme={navigationTheme}>
        {user ? <AppNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator /> }
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

package.js

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
    "@react-native-community/hooks": "^2.8.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.4.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^5.0.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.3.5",
    "apisauce": "^1.1.1",
    "expo": "~44.0.0",
    "expo-blur": "~11.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "^13.0.2",
    "expo-image-picker": "~12.0.1",
    "expo-location": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~11.1.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
    "formik": "^2.1.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.26.0",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    "react-native-expo-image-cache": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.8.6",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^3.1.0",
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.3.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AppLoading onError prop is required
```

You do no pass the error prop

```
<AppLoading startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />
```

Comment: Sorry, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: <AppLoading onError={INSERTYOURPROPSHERE} startAsync={restoreUser} onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)} />